# Borel sigma-algebra generated by...?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show that Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by the collection of all intervals of the form $(x,y]$. How?

Comment: what is the borel sigma algebra on R?

Comment: What definition are you using for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: There are many definitions? :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $$(a, b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a, b - \frac{1}{n}]$$

Comment: I have no idea how to formulate the proof :/

Comment: @PrincessAmazia Do you know that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the open intervals?

Comment: Yes, but I'm having some trouble with technical details and notation. I'm not a math student, I just want to understand the basics.